# Ubuntu server install fail and now a localhost login page shows up - but my user and password dont work here

Tags: server, system-installation, login

Tried installing 22.04.1 LTS today , it failed every time after setting the storage configuration. On the last try, it would not reboot on it own after sending the error report, so I just turned the computer off. Now when I turn it on, it goes to a localhost.localdomain tty1 page, with a prompt for a localhost login and password. The login and password I set do not work. I am at a complete loss as to how to move forward.

Comment: I tried to get it to boot from usb for a fresh install of 22.04 - no dice. I tried to boot from Ubuntu desktop, and it is taking me through the regular installation - it detected 22.04 LTS on there, and reformatted partitions. Will try again after this desktop installs. ( Was previously installing on a new machine that came pre-loaded with windows)

Comment: I have the same problem. Installation process just did nothing anymore after some minutes, I left it keeping doing whatever it maybe did in the background over the entire night, came back to see that nothing changed. I shut it down, booted it up again to get prompted exactly to that login and am stuck of how to proceed.